Procedure for constructing magic state gate injection gadgets
I have a quantum computer that cannot implement the gate $U$ by itself, and needs help in the form of a magic state $|U\rangle$ held in another register. Is there a general-purpose procedure for constructing a gate injection circuit that performs $|\psi\rangle \mapsto U|\psi\rangle$, by making use of (and likely consuming) $|U\rangle$?
What I know:
Beverland et al. 2019 gave a circuit construction for the case that $U$ is diagonal, which consumes the magic state $U|{+}^n\rangle$ (consisting of the entries of $U$'s diagonal, flattened into a vector). Despite only working for diagonal $U$ this is a very useful construction since it can inject non-Clifford gates like T, CS, and CCZ/Toffoli. Furthermore the authors show that the required classically-controlled corrections lie one level lower than $U$ in the Clifford hierarchy since they take the form $UX_iU^\dagger$, meaning third-level gates like CCZ can be injected into a Clifford computer.
Heyfron and Campbell 2018 gave an injection circuit for $H$ which consumes the state $|+\rangle$. This seemed a bit useless to me at first since $H$ is Clifford anyway, but it allows compiler passes targeting CNOT+T layers (what you might call 'phase gadget optimizers') to optimize around $H$ gates, since the injection circuit only uses gates from CNOT+T, which is brilliant. I've since seen this idea applied again in Ruiz et al. 2024. If there's a way to come up with this $H$-injection gadget using Beverland et al.'s procedure, I don't see it.
What I would like to know:

Is there a general-purpose procedure for creating a gate injection circuit for any given (non-diagonal) $U$? Preferably the magic state $|U\rangle$ would be defined by the procedure itself.

Are there more examples of gate injection constructions in the literature?


